# autoplot does not pick correctly thickness of plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, zoo, quantmod

Let's consider very simple plot created by autoplot :

```
library(ggplot2)
library(quantmod)



start <- as.Date("2013-01-01")
end <- as.Date("2016-10-01")
# Apple stock
getSymbols("AAPL", src = "yahoo", from = start, to = end) 
autoplot(Cl(AAPL), size = 1)
```

[image]

AS you can see above, autoplot picked the tickest option to plot, whereas I picked `size = 1`. Do you know where is the problem and how it can be solved ?

Comment: Can you try `size = I(1)`? This will try to set the size as literal `1` instead of mapping `1` to a scale of sizes and use the rescaled 1 as the linewidth.

Comment: It's working! Thanks dude